# cakephp documentation

Tags: php, documentation, cakephp-1.3

Is there an automated way or utility that can be used to document a cakephp application.  The client is requiring I provide technical documentation for others that will be working on the site, so I need a way to list out all the views, controllers, models, components, and helpers.  At least I need some sort of skeletal documentation that I can fill in with more meaningful instructions and descriptions.   Any links to anything that can do this would be helpful.

Comment: did you write docblock style comments?

Comment: i haven't, but I can go through and add them.

Comment: ok, i've read up on DocBlock from the phpdocumentor web site, so in my controllers and models, I have to set up these comments, I'm not seeing a way of documenting my views with comments like this, then I guess I'll need to build the documentation when I get this done.  I've got all weekend to get this right, as I'm providing the documentation to him on Monday.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you could document the views by placing the comment that goes at the top of the file. The view files are `.ctp`, but are, of course, PHP files. Not sure what all you intend to put in there, but that should get you pretty far.

Comment: The general idea is if you use docblock as part of your development methodology, then you can always autogenerate basic docs at will. Its a good practice to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use docbook for you PHP classes and methods. phpdoc also allows you to include external files with documentation for i.e. your views.